# Multiple domain names pointing on the same server but not on the same project

Tags: apache, vhosts, domain-name

I actually have two projects on my server

```
var/www/
-project1
-project2
```

I made this vhost to have access to project1 through domain1.com

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xxx:80>
ServerName domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/project1/
</VirtualHost>
```

so now my main IP is redirecting every request to /var/www/project1/

So how can i access to project2 through domain2.com (or just with something like xx.xx.xx.xxx/project2) ?

I'm not adminsys so it's probably not the good way to do it, can someone explain which is the right way to do to have access to each project through different domain name.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Have you tried adding the VirtualHost block a second time, with another domain?

Answer (score 0):

Much like you did for the first. You need to make sure you also have domain2 registered in DNS with the same IP.

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xxx:80>
   ServerName domain2.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/project2/
</VirtualHost>
```

If you're using apache version < 2.4, you also need to make sure you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere in your main configuration